# Why doesn't hotspot shield work on XP?

Tags: windows-xp, vpn, connection, hotspot-shield

I installed it on win 7 and it worked fine, but on XP I connect and it says CONNECTED successfully, however when I try to go to any website I can't, it doesn't load, as if the connection was lost. And when I disconnect Hotspot shield the internet connection is back again.

Any help to solve this problem?

Comment: What type of Internet connection do you have?  It works on my WinXP, and I use a wireless broadband connection.